SAPB1if (SAP Business One Integration Framework) B1Object atom is not updating anything on SAPB1, what am I missing?
I have a step in the B1if that is supposed, at a certain point, to update a SalesQuotation (object 23) filling the NumAtCard field in the header. It should just do that, given a DocEntry I fetched earlier and a string I'm composing, updating the NumAtCard with such string. While I'm not getting any error of sort, the SalesQuotation is not updating, not only the interested field, but not even the changelog telling me that the B1if did an empty update on that document.
I created a B1Object atom and a XSLTransform predecessor atom.
The B1Object atom looks like this:
B1Object atom configuration
The SysId xPath is surely correct because it's the same I use for a previous SQLCall atom and that one is working properly. The KeyValue xPath is also returning the correct DocEntry, as I can see in the MessageLog result (image after the XSLTransform code).
This is the code in my XSLTransform atom:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><xsl:stylesheet xmlns:b1e="urn:com.sap.b1i.sim:b1event" xmlns:b1ie="urn:com.sap.b1i.sim:b1ievent" xmlns:b1im="urn:com.sap.b1i.sim:b1imessage" xmlns:bfa="urn:com.sap.b1i.bizprocessor:bizatoms" xmlns:jdbc="urn:com.sap.b1i.adapter:jdbcadapter" xmlns:js="com.sap.b1i.bpc_tools.Javascript" xmlns:rfc="urn:sap-com:document:sap:rfc:functions" xmlns:sim="urn:com.sap.b1i.sim:entity" xmlns:uplt="urn:com.sap.b1i.xcellerator:upltdoc" xmlns:utils2="com.sap.b1i.bpc_tools.Utilities" xmlns:vpf="urn:com.sap.b1i.vplatform:entity" xmlns:xci="urn:com.sap.b1i.xcellerator:intdoc" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0" bfa:force="" vpf:force="" jdbc:force="" rfc:force="" b1ie:force="" b1e:force="" xci:force="" sim:force="" utils2:force="" b1im:force="" uplt:force="" js:force=""><xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"></xsl:output><xsl:param name="atom"></xsl:param><xsl:param name="sessionid"></xsl:param><xsl:variable name="msg" select="/vpf:Msg/vpf:Body/vpf:Payload[./@Role=&apos;S&apos;]"></xsl:variable><xsl:variable name="vpSender" select="/vpf:Msg/vpf:Header/vpf:Sender/@Id"></xsl:variable><xsl:variable name="vpObject" select="/vpf:Msg/vpf:Header/vpf:Sender/@ObjId"></xsl:variable><xsl:variable name="vpReceiver" select="/vpf:Msg/vpf:Header/vpf:ReceiverList/vpf:Receiver[./@handover=&apos;P&apos;]/@Id"></xsl:variable><xsl:variable name="vpEccFileDirectory" select="/vpf:Msg/vpf:Header/vpf:Properties/vpf:prop[./@id=&apos;EccFileDirectory&apos;]/@value"></xsl:variable><xsl:variable name="vpCloudAccount" select="/vpf:Msg/vpf:Header/vpf:Properties/vpf:prop[./@id=&apos;CloudAccount&apos;]/@value"></xsl:variable><xsl:variable name="vpCloudCompany" select="/vpf:Msg/vpf:Header/vpf:Properties/vpf:prop[./@id=&apos;CloudCompany&apos;]/@value"></xsl:variable><xsl:variable name="vpCloudPassword" select="/vpf:Msg/vpf:Header/vpf:Properties/vpf:prop[./@id=&apos;CloudPassword&apos;]/@value"></xsl:variable><xsl:variable name="vpCloudHost" select="/vpf:Msg/vpf:Header/vpf:Properties/vpf:prop[./@id=&apos;CloudHost&apos;]/@value"></xsl:variable><xsl:variable name="vpCloudUsername" select="/vpf:Msg/vpf:Header/vpf:Properties/vpf:prop[./@id=&apos;CloudUsername&apos;]/@value"></xsl:variable><xsl:template match="/"><xsl:variable name="vptsDoc" select="document(&apos;/com.sap.b1i.internal/xml/timestamp&apos;)"></xsl:variable><xsl:variable name="vpts" select="concat($vptsDoc/*/@year,&apos;/&apos;,$vptsDoc/*/@month,&apos;/&apos;,$vptsDoc/*/@date,&apos; &apos;,$vptsDoc/*/@hour,&apos;:&apos;,$vptsDoc/*/@minute,&apos;:&apos;,$vptsDoc/*/@second)"></xsl:variable><Msg xmlns="urn:com.sap.b1i.vplatform:entity">
            <xsl:copy-of select="/vpf:Msg/@*"></xsl:copy-of>
            <xsl:copy-of select="/vpf:Msg/vpf:Header"></xsl:copy-of>

            <Body>
                <xsl:copy-of select="/vpf:Msg/vpf:Body/*"></xsl:copy-of>
                <Payload Role="X" id="{$atom}">
                    <xsl:call-template name="transform"></xsl:call-template>
                </Payload>
            </Body>
        </Msg></xsl:template><xsl:template name="transform">
        <Documents>
            <row>
                <NumAtCard>
                    <xsl:value-of select="concat(&apos;SCL&apos;, /vpf:Msg/vpf:Body/vpf:Payload/jdbc:SqlResult/jdbc:ResultSet/jdbc:Row[./jdbc:ID=&apos;Head&apos;]/jdbc:callID)"></xsl:value-of>
                </NumAtCard>
            </row>
        </Documents>
    </xsl:template></xsl:stylesheet>

The fact is that the resulting payload for the B1Object atom is a success, with no error message, DI failure or else, so the template and the configuration looks to be fine. Despite that, my SalesQuotation is not updating at all. I can't even see an empty update from the B1i user (like it should be if I had a good template but empty content).
messagelog XML
SAP changelog
What am I missing? Why it's not updating the SalesQuotation despite me following the template B1if provided for that document, the B1Object giving "success" as a result, the NumAtCard being passed and the docentry corresponding to the intended document?
